# Independent Poisson Variable

Tags: probability

The number of people arriving at a post office in a day is a poisson random variable with parameter λ. If each person who enters the post office is male with probability p and female with probability 1-p, show that that the number of males arriving at a post office in a day is a poisson random variable with parameter λp and number of females arriving at the post office in a day is a poisson random variable with parameter λ(1-p).

The proof to this in my book starts as follows

Let X denote the number of males arriving, Y number of females arriving

P ( X = a, y = b) = P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) P ( X + Y = a + b)  + P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) P ( X + Y ≠ a + b)

Second part = 0 , So

(1) P ( X = a, y = b) = P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) P ( X + Y = a + b)

(2) P ( X + Y = a + b) = [e ^ (-λ)] [λ ^ (a+b)] / (a+b)!   (the poisson probability)

(3) P ( X = a, Y = b | X + Y = a + b) = (a + b choose a) (p ^ a) ((1-p) ^ b)

I don't seem to understand why in (3) , given a+b arrive, the probability that (a) of them are male and (b) of them are female is binomial

Comment: $a+b$ persons arrive (so $a+b$ independent experiments). Let's say that the experiment is "successful" if the person is male. The probability on succes is $p$. These are the characteristics of a binomial distribution, right?

Comment: I sort of worked it out by imagining the experiment as throwing a 3 sided die - one side male, one side female, one side no arrival. So , P ( X=a, Y = b  | X+Y = a + b)   = P ( a males, b females, n- (a+b) failures) /  P ( (a+b) successes and n - (a+b) failures ) where the probability of male = p success * p male, probability of female = p success * p female. Would that be a accurate way of framing the problem?

Comment: Sorry just one more question as well, the conclusion of the proof is that X and Y are independent poisson random variables with parameters  λp and λ(1-p) respectively but if a poisson is the limiting case of binomial shouldnt X and Y be dependant. So using the same example of the 3 sided die and n independent trials, wouldnt P (X = a | Y= b)  ≠ P (X = a)?

Comment: If I would tell you that $20$ arrivals where there today, then what would be your conclusion about the distribution of the number of males that arrived today?

Comment: P ( no of male arrivals = i ) = (20 choose i) (p ^ i) ( (1-p)^ (20-i))

Comment: Correct,  and that exactly the statement that under condition  $X+Y=20$ the distribution of $X$ is binomial with parameters  $n=20$ and $p$ as stated in (3).